# How do I find Cortana Music searches online?

Tags: 8.1, cortana, search

I've used cortana's music search function on my Windows Phone 8.1 device.  I would like to view these searches online.  How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "view online"? You want to see a history of what you've searched in the browser?

Comment: @Thomas yes.  There are times that I don't have access to my phone but would like to see those searches.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no online accessible copy of your music search history. You'll have to save it manually for example in OneNote.